# Short freezes for touchpad on Acer Nitro 5

Tags: nvidia, mouse, touchpad, freeze

##### Problem

The touchpad on my Acer Nitro 5 has the following issue under Kubuntu 22.04: When I start moving my finger on the touchpad, the mouse on the screen will move for ~0.5 sec, then stop for ~0.5 sec, then move again all the time as expected. The PC remains operative but it these short freezes are very annoying.
The curious thing is that the problem is gone after a second monitor is attached.

##### [My solution ideas:

I have learned that an external monitor often runs on the external GPU for several notebook models. So I think this has to do with internal or external GPU settings.
My assumptions are supported by the fact that `sudo prime-select nvidia` (i.e. only external GPU utilized) solves the mouse problem; but to save battery time, I would like to stick with the default `sudo prime-select on-demand` (where I assume the internal GPU is used mainly).
I have a Nvidia 3050Ti as external graphic card, but changing drivers (I tested nvidia-535, nvidia-470 and the noveau driver) has no effect.]

##### My workaround

My current workaround is to restart the notebook after an external monitor is detached. Somehow the touchpad works fine afterwards.
If you have similar problems or have an idea to fix it, an answer would be great! Thank you!